# Connect6 - How to code checkWinner method correctly/efficent?

Tags: java

im currently writing a textbased connect6 game(wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect6) with java. But i´m not sure how to code the method which checks after a players turn whether he won or not correctly. Do i really have to mention and go through every single possible wincondition. So for example: Havin one colour in the coordinates x:0 y:0, x:0 y:1, x:0 y:2, x:0 y:3, x:0 y:4, x:0 y:5 would be a possible wincondition. Do i have to check every single win condition with an if statement or is there a faster/ more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: You need to check them, probably inside a for-loop. But for better help sooner please post a valid [mcve]

Comment: No you dont need all win combinations. Try sketch some ideas on paper so you can work out how to best process it. However here is a suggestion to get you started: When a chip is inserted only check the 8 spaces around it, and then if there is one of the right color then check the color of the next chip in that direction. When you get to the end of a line check in the opposite direction as well in case the recently inserted tile is in the middle of a line. You should be able to do this with something like a single loop and a bunch of nested if statements.